# Reading price chart from Bitmex API json conversion issue

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

I want to develop strategies for Bitmex. To do some testing I would like to have vectors of the OHCL and VOLUME vectors separately. I implemented the following code:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

url1 = 'https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/trade/bucketed?binSize=1h&partial=false&symbol=XBT&count=150&start='
url2 = '&reverse=true'

ohcl = url1 + '0' + url2

u = urlopen(ohcl)
data = json.loads(u)

print(type(data))
```

Unfortunately the `data` is stored as a list, I am unable to reference it like a dict (e.g. `data[high]`) . It is a hodgepodge of strings and numbers. Fields are not defined.

How do I access the fields and/or convert them to separate vectors?

Comment: should have used load instead of loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you `data` is a `list`, you need to iterate over this list.

```
for stock in data:
    print('symbol: {symbol} - high: {high} - low: {low}'.format(symbol=stock['symbol'], high=stock['high'], low=stock['low']))
```

Comment: The printed output is certainly less messy! I'll try to load the values to different variables.

Comment: This is a example how to handle with data. Hope it helps.